# how to prevent absolute position span from moving up when text inside is wrapped

Tags: html, css

I have a form with error messages that are positioned absolutely. But when the text wraps, the position of the error message moves up and overlaps the inputs. How do I make it wrap to the next line but make the top line of the error message stay in it's original position? Below is an example:

```css
.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 10%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.error {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: .9rem;
  font-size: .8rem;
  
}

button {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.input-container {
  position: relative;
}

.input-container > input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <form>
    <div class="input-container">

      <input type="text"/>  
      <span class="error">error msg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-container">

      <input type="text"/>  
      <span class="error">error msg wrapped</span>
    </div>
    <button>
      submit
    </button>
  </form>

</div>
```

as you can see in the first input field's error message, that placement is fine. The problem is the next line where it overlaps the input. How can i make it wrap to the available white space below it?

Comment: you have discovered that position:absolute is not the way to go. Remove it and simply toggle the display of the element to show/hide it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple. You should not use `position: absolute` in this case. Remove it from `.error` styles and add a `padding-bottom` to `.input-container` for spacement. Turn `.error` elements into divs and set a `height` value to it according to the error message length, so when it wraps, it will occupy the space below.

```css
.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 10%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.error {
  color: red;
  bottom: .9rem;
  font-size: .8rem;
  height: 30px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.input-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.input-container > input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <form>
    <div class="input-container">

      <input type="text"/>  
      <div class="error">error msg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-container">

      <input type="text"/>  
      <div class="error">error msg wrapped</div>
    </div>
    <button>
      submit
    </button>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: yeah..i mean the issue is that i want the fields and buttons to remain in their position so they don't move when an error message appears.

Comment: I have made some changes to the answer, now I think it will solve your problem in a more appropriate way.